# Why does fread(fmtChunkId, sizeof(char), 4, fp); read 11 characters?

Tags: c++, char, declaration, fread

Here is the part of the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
fread(fmtChunkId, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
if(strcmp(fmtChunkId, "WAVE") != 0) {
    cout << "Not WAVE format: " << fmtChunkId << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it prints `Not WAVE format: WAVE    e∞@` which is 11 characters long instead of 4. However, it works properly when I replace `fmtChunkId` with `type`, which confuses me because I declared those two variables the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /*Get file path*/
    char filepath[261];
    cout << "Please enter the file path of a .wav file: ";
    cin.getline(filepath, sizeof(filepath));
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(filepath, "rb");
    if(!fp) {
        cout << "Failed to open file: " << filepath;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << endl;

    /*Declarations*/
    char type[4];
    char riffChunkId[4];
    int riffChunkSize;
    char fmtChunkId[4];
    int fmtChunkSize;
    short audioFormat;
    short numChannels;
    int sampleRate;
    int byteRate;
    short blockAlign;
    short bitsPerSample;
    int dataSize;

    /*Read file data*/
    fread(riffChunkId, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(strcmp(riffChunkId, "RIFF") != 0) {
        cout << "Not RIFF format: " << riffChunkId << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    fread(&riffChunkSize, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(fmtChunkId, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(strcmp(fmtChunkId, "WAVE") != 0) {
        cout << "Not WAVE format: " << fmtChunkId << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(strcmp(type, "fmt ") != 0) {
        cout << "Not fmt: " << type << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    fread(&fmtChunkSize, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(&audioFormat, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(&numChannels, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(&sampleRate, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(&byteRate, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(&blockAlign, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(&bitsPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
    if(strcmp(type, "data") != 0) {
        cout << "Not data: " << type << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    fread(&dataSize, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    /*Print file data*/
    cout << "RIFF Chunk Size: " << riffChunkSize << endl;
    cout << "fmt Chunk Size: " << fmtChunkSize << endl;
    cout << "Audio Format: " << audioFormat << endl;
    cout << "Number of Channels: " << numChannels << endl;
    cout << "Sample Rate: " << sampleRate << endl;
    cout << "byteRate: " << byteRate << endl;
    cout << "blockAlign: " << blockAlign << endl;
    cout << "Bits Per Sample: " << bitsPerSample << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read [**How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**]  At least leave us with a **[MCVE]** that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Comment: To expand, your char array can hold 4 characters. You read 4 characters but then also need to append a null byte because fread doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literal `"WAVE"` is actually 5 bytes long, since C-style strings must end with a null character `\0`. Since you declared `type` and `fmtChunkId` with only 4 chars, the `strcmp` function and `cout <<` statement actually keep reading past the end of the 4 bytes until it hits a `\0`. (This can cause a segfault if it doesn't hit a `\0` before it runs into unauthorized memory).

So, with `fmtChunkId`, it printed out a few extra characters of garbage, because that's what it found in memory before the next `\0`. With `type`, the next byte happened to be `\0`, and so it accidentally worked.

One solution, as other commenters mentioned, is to initialize your strings to a length of 5, and set the last byte to 0 after `fread` but before `strcmp`.

A more eloquent solution is to use [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/), which compares bytes directly (which is what you really want) instead of strings:

```
fread(fmtChunkId, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
if(memcmp(fmtChunkId, "WAVE", 4) != 0) {
    cout << "Not WAVE format" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```